# Log in with the root account

Tags: 16.04

How do I log on to my root account when I turn on my computer instead of logging on as an ordinary user? This means that when I log in with my root account, any software is opened by default root and has all the rights to the file.

Comment: Please install another operating system if you want that; like debian. Ubuntu is set to be used with "sudo" including correct, traceable, logging. Yes, it is possible but that does not mean it is a good idea.

Comment: Please promise you won't ask how to recover accidentally deleted files, dropped packages and messed up configurations.

Comment: There is a reason that this is not possible. I don't want to be rude but.....It's like asking if you could bring your dog to a store and there is a sign in front of the store which clearly states, No dogs allowed! And you still keep asking how you could bring your dog. My opinion matches that of rinzwind. Please use another operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give you an answer, but first here's a warning.

#### It's dangerous to do this, and usually not recommended at all; you're better off using `sudo`. I myself have had my system destroyed this way when I was kind of new to Linux.

However, here's how you do this if you really want to risk a broken system:

1. Fire up a terminal
2. Execute `sudo -i`
3. Enter your password
4. Run `passwd`
5. Enter a secure password for the `root` user (different from your main user)
6. Repeat the password
7. Run `nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`(replace nano with the text editor of your choice)
8. Add:

   ```
   [SeatDefaults]
   greeter-session=unity-greeter
   user-session=ubuntu
   greeter-show-manual-login=true
   ```

   to the bottom of said file.

If you followed these steps you should be able to login as `root`, but as I said before: don't do this if you don't know what can go wrong.

Source: [configserverfirewall.com](http://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/enable-ubuntu-desktop-root-login/)

Answer (score 1):

Its also possible to add your "ordinary user" to groups, that would allow you to edit files. Like, say, add to apache group, if you play with /etc/apache files. Alternatively, you can change the owner of the files you need, with chown 'ordinary user' /etc/apache/conf... - use with caution ( dont do chown ... /etc/* :-)